On little-o notation and exponent
I need to get asymptotic for $(3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^n$
My attempt is: $(3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^n = 3^n(1 + \frac{1}{3\sqrt{n}})^n = 3^n((1 + \frac{1}{3\sqrt{n}})^{3\sqrt{n}})^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}}=3^ne^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}(1+o(1))}$
my question is: why do we put $1 + o(1)$ in power, but not in base? we  know, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$ so it would be more intuitive to do $3^n((1 + \frac{1}{3\sqrt{n}})^{3\sqrt{n}})^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}}=3^n(e(1+o(1))^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}} = 3^ne^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}}(1+o(1))^{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3}}$
are these two results similar to each other? and if yes, how can we prove it?
